# where remains exec query data context?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the exec("query_string") command on sql server. The matter is that the changes executed by this command cannot seen outside.

I mean that, I try to create a temp table with dynamic columns in a exec command an it runs ok, but when I try to make a select statement over created table I receive a error message that says that the table does not exists.

I know that is a context problem and my cuestion is how I make to exec command runs on a same context just like other sql statements???

```
CREATE TABLE #Test ( TheDate datetime, Harvest int )
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2011/10/11', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2012/10/11', 100)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2011/10/01', 20)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2011/12/11', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2011/11/11', 50)
INSERT INTO #Test(TheDate, Harvest) VALUES ('2011/11/12', 150)

DECLARE @listCol2 varchar(max)
SET @listCol2 = 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ('[' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(TheDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(TheDate)),2) +'] date,')
     FROM #Test
     ORDER BY ('[' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(TheDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(TheDate)),2) +'] date,') ASC
     FOR XML PATH(''))
SET  @listCol2 = LEFT(@listCol2,LEN(@listCol2)-1)
SELECT  @listCol2

EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #Test2 ('+@listCol2+')') 

SELECT * FROM #Test2 --In this line I got this message: the name of the object #Test2 isn't valid, why???

DROP TABLE #Test2

DROP TABLE #Test
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have following options.

```
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #Test2 ('+@listCol2+'); Select * from #test2') 



EXEC ('CREATE TABLE ##Test2 ('+@listCol2+')') 

SELECT * FROM ##Test2 --it will not throws the name of the object isn't valid

DROP TABLE ##Test2


EXEC ('CREATE TABLE Test2 ('+@listCol2+')') 

SELECT * FROM Test2 --it will not throws the name of the object isn't valid

DROP TABLE Test2
```

Comment: Yeah the solution that worked for me is ##Test2 but what is the meaning of a double sharp????

Comment: Ya. This table resides on database server.

Comment: It's a Global table and accessible to all user... Unlike the Local Temporary variable whose scope is defined in the current session.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx):

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped
>   automatically when the stored procedure is finished.

Since your EXEC (...) is in effect a call to a stored proce (think [`sp_executesql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)) the `#Test2` is out of scope, hence dropped, when you try to select from it. You must place the SELECT in the same EXEC:

```
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #Test2 ('+@listCol2+'); SELECT * FROM #Test2');
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. If i create a temp table with this name ##Test2 it works!!!! :)

Comment: Of course `##Temp2` works becaus eis a **global** temp table. But is incorrect because now two distinct users/sessions will create/select the *same* global temp table which will lead to all sort of race conditions and random crashes/failures you'll grow old tryign to investigate/fix...

Answer (score 0):

Your table is created wrong and therefore does not exist. The query for #test2 table should be like this. Date is not a defined field.

```
CREATE TABLE #Test2 ([2011-10] datetime,[2011-11] datetime,[2011-12] datetime,[2012-10] datetime)
```

If I modify your sql like this and run it, I get this error

> The name 'CREATE TABLE #Test2 ([2011-10] date,[2011-11] date,[2011-12]
>   date,[2012-10] date)' is not a valid identifier.

Modified Code

```
DECLARE @listCol2 varchar(max)
SET @listCol2 = 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ('[' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(TheDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(TheDate)),2) +'] date,')
     FROM #Test
     ORDER BY ('[' + CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(TheDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(varchar,MONTH(TheDate)),2) +'] date,') ASC
     FOR XML PATH(''))
SET  @listCol2 = LEFT(@listCol2,LEN(@listCol2)-1)
SELECT  @listCol2

DECLARE @q varchar(4000)
set @q= 'CREATE TABLE #Test2 ('+@listCol2+')'

exec @q
```

Comment: Issue will still come as #temp2 is not accessible after the dynamic query execution. can you please modify your post..I will not downvote it.

Comment: The problem here is #test2 is not created, the error simply is not shown. If it is not created, you are querying against invalid object.

Comment: OP is trying to access the #temp after line exec @q and the object becomes invalid after this line of code.

Comment: Nope. He can never access it after it is created. I updated my answer.

Comment: Date it´s a valid datatype. But after I created the table with exec then I try to make a select and this fails

Comment: This is the true reason: A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished.